Last element of sequence but with a break if a condition is met
Let say I have a Sequence<Int> of unknown origin (not necessarily from a collection) and unknown but finite size:
val seq = sequenceOf(1, 2, -3, 4, 5, /* ... */)

Assume the sequence is large enough to make it undesirable to turn the whole sequence into a List.
I want to get the last element of the sequence:
val last = seq.last()

But I also want to catch any "invalid" element that might appear (let's say negative numbers are invalid) and return the first such element:
val invalid = seq.first { it < 0 }

But how can I do both of those at the same time?
val lastUnlessInvalidElementPresent = seq.firstOrNull { it < 0 } ?: seq.last()

The problem is that ?: seq.last() doesn't work because by the time firstOrNull has returned null, the whole sequence has been consumed.
I can do this iteratively, but would prefer a functional solution.

FWIW, in a hybrid language like Kotlin, many of the stdlib functions that let you write functional-style code are actually implemented with imperative-style code, at least in part; that seems to be a good compromise, as purely functional code can be complex and/or perform badly.  So there's no shame in using that approach yourself (as the first two answers demonstrate).

You can use fold() with a simple data class that holds your value plus a flag indicating whether you're still in "get last" mode or already in "encountered an invalid value, let's keep it" mode:
data class Elem(val value: Int, val valid: Boolean)

fun main() {
    val seq = sequenceOf(1, 2, -3, 4, 5, /* ... */)
    val initial = Elem(0, true)
    val lastUnlessInvalidElementPresent = seq.fold(Elem(0, true), 
       { acc, item -> if (acc.valid && item < 0) { Elem(item, false) }   // first invalid element
                      else if (acc.valid) { Elem(item, true) } // valid element, keep looking
                      else { acc } // already found an invalid element - keep it
       }
    )
    println(lastUnlessInvalidElementPresent)
}

This approach has two disadvantages, though:

the fold() will still consume the complete sequence even after encountering an invalid element
you need a sensible "default" element to initialize your value

Playground

Thanks - marking as accepted as it's a pure functional approach, but I find Leviathan's answer more readable despite being iterative.

I don't think this can be easily done with the built-in functions because last is a somewhat special predicate.
Adapting the existing lastOrNull to test for the first occurrence of a predicate (it < 0) would look like this:
inline fun <T> Sequence<T>.firstMatchOrLastOrNull(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    var last: T? = null
    for (element in this) {
        if (predicate(element)) return element
        last = element
    }
    return last
}

Now you can use seq.firstMatchOrLastOrNull { it < 0 } to get what you want. This shouldn't be different, performance-wise, from the built-in functions.

In the end I've come up with my own succinct solution:
fun <T> Sequence<T>.firstMatchOrLastOrNull(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    var last: T? = null
    return onEach { last = it }.firstOrNull(predicate) ?: last
}

fun main() {
    println(sequenceOf(1, 2, -3, 4, 5).firstMatchOrLastOrNull { it < 0 }) // -3
    println(sequenceOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).firstMatchOrLastOrNull { it < 0 })  // 5
}

It's almost functional, but it's not pure functional because it uses a mutable variable.

fun <T> Sequence<T>.firstMatchOrLastOrNull(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
  return this.find(predicate) ?: this.lastOrNull()
}

println(sequenceOf(1, 2, -3, 4, 5).firstMatchOrLastOrNull { it < 0 })   // -3
println(sequenceOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).firstMatchOrLastOrNull { it < 0 })    // 5
println(sequenceOf<Int>().firstMatchOrLastOrNull { it < 0 })            // null


Thanks, this works for some sequences, but not those that can be iterated only once, because both find and lastOrNull are terminal operations.
